# Windows Authentication in Blazor WASM

Tags: authentication, blazor, windows-authentication, blazor-webassembly

I am implementing a WebApp in our company's intranet with Blazor WebAssembly. I need to make API-Calls to our DevOps Server hosted in our intranet and need to use Windows Authentication to access the API. In the former used WPF Client it was enough to just add the `UseDefaultCredentials`-Flag on the HttpClient, but that does not work in WebAssembly anymore since the App is running in the browser. The Microsoft Docs state `We don't recommend using Windows Authentication with Blazor Webassembly`, but not recommend does not mean not support, so it has to be possible somehow, to attach the current App-User's Windows Credentials(Token) to the API Call. Unfortunately there exists no example on the docs page on how to implement this and I have not found any code on how to tackle this, although on some forums people wrote that it is possible, but did not include the `How` in their comments.

I am using .NET5 for both Server and Client and need to make the Api-Call with Windows Authentication from the **Client**, not the **Server** as most examples are using it, as my Server-Project uses the same User for all Requests but I need the User of the Client-Project.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: That last part is not entirely clear. Do you want to "authorize" on the Client?  Or just establish the User in your API endpoints?  To what server(s) does the Client talk?

Comment: Isn't [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-microsoft-accounts?view=aspnetcore-5.0) what you want?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I want to authorize the User on the API such that the response includes the items for the given User on the client (e.g. Tickets or more generally Workitems). The Client talks to an ASP.NET Core WebAPI also hosted in the intranet and furthermore should also be able to send Requests (using Windows Authentication) to the intranet hosted DevOps App

Comment: @Grizzlly this is talking about Microsoft Accounts and Azure AD, I need to leverage the currently signed in Windows User

Comment: this is the way: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio